# How can I customize the color of the editor gutter in VS Code?

Tags: themes, visual-studio-code, background-color

In VS Code Themes I am looking for the names of the line-number bar (background)-color-options. There is no theme with different background of the line-numbers-"panel" - every theme I am testing is the same background like the document-window itself. It´s nice in design, but i click often the line-numbers instead of line-start.

Can anybody tell me the theme-name of this background color for this panel? Like "editorLineNumber.foreground" - but there is no "editorLineNumber.background"-option and I didn't find / know what to look - or what to write ;) A visible border would work, too, but the background color would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `editorGutter.background` property as in:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorGutter.background": "#fff5"
}
```