# How can I customize the colour of the editor gutter in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv6Hg.png) I'm trying to modify background colors from Visual Studio Code and can't found the reference of this line number bar to change it!

I have tried with different names, but can't find the right one.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: oh. found the actual duplicate after answering. [Name of elements for coloring / theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46269452/name-of-elements-for-coloring-theme) (pretty terrible title over there. I just edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the colour customization point you're looking for is `"editorGutter.background"`.

Ex.

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorGutter.background": "#ff0000"
}
```

Or to make it apply only for a specific colour theme:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[<Theme Name>]":
        "editorGutter.background": "#ff0000"
    }
}
```